# Modifying SAS dataset using condition

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have a dataset in SAS Enterprise Guide that looks like this:

ID | Year | Entity | Inv1 | Inv2 | Inv3 | Inv4 | Inv5
1  |  2015  |  A  |  2  | 3    | . |    5    |     .
1  |  2016 |   A   |  .  |      2 |     3  |   .  |  .
2  |  2015  |  B   |     1  |  .  |      3   |  .    |     4
3 |   2016  |   C  |   .  |       2  |   .   |     3   |  .
2 |   2016  |   B   |     5 |   .   | .   | 2  |.
3  |  2015 |    C   |   .  |1     |    .    |    .|   3

and I want to transform it into:

ID | Year | Entity | Inv | Value
1  |  2015   |  A  |    Inv1 |  2
1  |  2015  |   A  |    Inv2 |  3
1  |  2015   |  A   |   Inv4 |  5
1  |  2016  |  A   |   Inv2  | 2
1  |  2016   |  A  |   Inv3  | 3
2  |  2015   |  B   |   Inv1 | 1
2  |  2015   |  B  |    Inv3  | 3
2  |  2015   |  B  |    Inv5  | 4
3  |  2016   |  C  |    Inv2 | 2
3  |  2016   |  C  |    Inv4  | 3
2  |  2016   |  B  |    Inv1  | 5
2  |  2016   |  B  |    Inv4  | 2
3  |  2015   |  C  |    Inv2 | 1
3  |  2015   |  C  |    Inv5  | 3

I have searched on the internet and I have come up with this: http://support.sas.com/kb/24/635.html but my problem has extra dimensions and I'm stuck. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: EG has a Transpose Task.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple transpose.

First sort your data:

```
proc sort data=have;
by id year entity;
run;
```

Then transpose.  You will rename columns and filter out the missing values:

```
proc transpose data=have out=want(where=(value1^=.)) name=Inv prefix=Value;
by id year entity;
var inv:;
run;
```

`Proc Transpose` will create the variable as `Value1`, you can rename that if you want.

```
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
modify want;
   rename Value1=Value;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: You could also do the rename as a dataset option on OUT=WANT.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an array and using it, iterate between `inv` variables.

```
 data result;
    set source;

    array inv_tab(*) inv1-inv5;

    do i = 1 to dim(inv_tab);
        if inv_tab(i) ^= . then do;
            inv = vname(inv_tab(i));
            value = inv_tab(i);
            output;
        end;
    end;

    drop i inv1-inv5;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

In EG, you can also use the Transpose Task.

Place the INV variables under the TRANSPOSE variables.
Place ID YEAR ENTITY under the GROUP BY variables

You can customize your output dataset name under the Results options.